# Understanding React export component error

Tags: reactjs

I have a typical React structure.

In the folder src I store index.js, in the folder src > components I store App.js, and in the folder src > components > navigation > components I store MainNavigation.js

For the past hour or so I'm trying to figure out the following error message:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './navigation/components/MainNavigation' in '/Users/raoul/Projects/pooper-scoopers/src/components'

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import { MainNavigation }  from "./navigation/components/MainNavigation";

export default function App() {
  return <div>This is App.js</div>;
}
```

Main.js

```
export default function MainNavigation() {
  return <div>This is the component MainNavigation.</div>;
}
```

The error is solved when I change Main.js to the following:

```
export function MainNavigation() {
  return <div>This is the component MainNavigation.</div>;
}
```

As you can see I removed default from the code to solve the problem. Only I have no idea why this solved the problem. Can you please explain?

Comment: you can clear your doubts here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I will read the documentation to get a better understanding.